# Storing radio button value into mysql database using laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

how can I insert value of this radion button in database

```
<label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="answers[{{ $questionOption->question->id }}]" value="{{ $questionOption->id }}">{{ $questionOption->option_one }}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use array as radio name. Radio button is intended to have single value.

```php
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{ $questionOption->id }}">{{ $questionOption->option_one }} <!-- option name? -->
</label>
```

And in `$request->answer` you have selected option id.